# Creating a branch on bitbucket.org and checking it out deleted my code

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I created a repo on bitbucket, tried to push my local code on my laptop to it, but it keeps writing this error:

```
    To https://bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

afterwards, I went to create a new branch on bitbucket.org and saw this:

> Check out your branch
>
> This branch does not contain any changes - check
>   it out on your local machine to do some work.
>
> Check out in Sourcetree
>
> You can also use this command to check out your branch:
>
> Checkout command: `git fetch && git checkout test_branch`

after running those commands, my entire code wiped off on my local machine. How do I get it back?

Requested info:

```
$ git reflog

MAC:thenestfour mac$ git reflog
c47ec7f (HEAD -> test_branch, origin/test_branch, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
c47ec7f (HEAD -> test_branch, origin/test_branch, origin/master) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
c47ec7f (HEAD -> test_branch, origin/test_branch, origin/master) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to test_branch
eb7abd8 (master) HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): secondtemplate for Omnibiz
```

Commands I'm running to push my local repo to my Bitbucket cloud repo:

```
MAC:thenestfour mac$ git push origin test_branch
```

Everything up-to-date
MAC:thenestfour mac$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

```
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

MAC:thenestfour mac$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

MAC:thenestfour mac$ git push --set-upstream origin master
To https://bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Wow, git checkout master brought back the code. thanks @AD7six

Answer (score 1):

#### Work is in the master branch

The output of `git reflog` includes:

```
moving from master to test_branch
```

This indicates you were previously on the master branch. Therefore to get the 
"lost" work back:

```
git checkout master
```

#### What happened

It looks like the branch created via bitbucket.org (I don't use it, so not sure) created an empty branch. As such, when checking out this new branch locally - it updated the local working copy to match i.e. created an empty directory.

#### Pushing changes to master

The original error was:

> Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally

It goes on to say:

> You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

The solution was in the response already i.e.:

```
git checkout master # Just in case still on a different branch
git pull
git push
```

Please consult any [getting started with git tutorial](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners) (there are many of them, find one to your liking) to get familiar with normal git workflows.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, everything in your solution works well, until the main issue. I have pulled and tried push again to the the repo. It still shows same error

Comment: please show the commands you are running and the output - by editing the question

Comment: Sorry, stack overflow isn't a support forum. If you have another question - please ask another question (but before doing so - please read a git tutorial). Note that "the main issue" is not what was asked, or even mentioned originally.